# Factoring of conditional probability

Tags: probability

I have been watching Tom Mitchell's lecture on Bayes Nets:

http://cc-web.isri.cmu.edu/CourseCast/Viewer/Default.aspx?id=bc507778-7a18-4121-b345-
83d9bab72f55

He states the following by way of the chain rule. I'm being dense I am sure but don't recognize this quickly. Is it a straight application of the chain rule?

$$P(x_3,x_4\ |\ Y) = P(x_3\  |\  Y, X_4 )P(X_4\  |\  Y)$$

Comment: Look closely at $P(A\cap B) = P(A|B)P(B)$.  Does that  help?

Comment: ...and use it repeatedly, if necessary.

Comment: I think the issue gets muddled in students' minds by the notation where commas indicate intersection and capitalization may (or may not!) mean different things. I would suggest writing $$\begin{align*}P(A\cap B\mid C) &= \frac{P(A\cap B \cap C)}{P(C)} = \frac{P(A\cap (B \cap C))}{P(C)}\\&= \frac{P(A\cap (B \cap C))}{P(B \cap C)}\times\frac{P(B \cap C)}{P(C)}\\&= P(A\mid (B\cap C))P(B\mid C).\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I like to think of the chain rule as:
$$P(A\cap B) = P(B)P(A\mid B) = P(A)P(B \mid A)$$
instead of $P(A\cap B) = P(B)P(A\mid B)$ which is the way G. Jay Kerns expressed
it in his comment on the question.
There is no mathematical difference, of course, but
we can think of $P(A\cap B) = P(A)P(B \mid A)$ as encapsulating the
following heuristic way of thinking.

> We want to find $P(A \cap B)$, the probability that both $A$ and $B$ 
>   occurred.  Clearly, $A$ must have occurred (which has probability $P(A)$),
>   and if we assume that $A$ has occurred, then in order for $A \cap B$ to
>   occur, $B$ must occur too, which has probability $P(B\mid A)$,
>   (note: **not** $P(B)$
>   since we have already assumed that $A$ has occurred), and so
>   $P(A \cap B) = P(A)P(B \mid A)$.

Generalizing this argument (which fortunately can be backed up
by straight mathematical calculations from the definition of
conditional probability),
$$P(A\cap B \cap C) = P(A)P(B\mid A)P(C\mid (A \cap B))$$
or, proceeding in the opposite direction,
$$P(A\cap B \cap C) = P(C)P(B\mid C)P(A\mid (B \cap C)).$$
Dividing this last equation on both sides by $P(C)$ gives
$$\begin{align*}
\frac{P(A\cap B \cap C)}{P(C)} 
&= \frac{P(C)P(B\mid C)P(A\mid B \cap C)}{P(C)}\\
P(A\cap B \mid C) &= P(B\mid C)P(A\mid (B \cap C))\\
&= P(A\mid (B \cap C))P(B\mid C)
\end{align*}$$
So the OP should accept that the equality follows from 
 the chain rule (plus an extra step).