# Splitting Probability Distributions Into Many Factors : The Deep Learning Book

Tags: probability, deep-learning, conditional-probability, random-variable

In chapter 3, section 3.14: Structured Probabilistic Models in [The Deep Learning Book](http://www.deeplearningbook.org) the authors write this, with the following equation.

> Machine learning algorithms often involve probability distributions over a very large number of random variables. Often, these probability distributions involve direct interactions between relatively few variables. Using a single function to describe the entire joint probability distribution can be very inefficient (both computationally and statistically)
>
> Instead of using a single function to represent a probability distribution, we can split a probability distribution into many factors that we multiply together.For example, suppose we have three random variables: a, b and c. Suppose that a inﬂuences the value of b, and b inﬂuences the value of c, but that a and c are independent given b. We can represent the probability distribution over all three variables as a product of probability distributions over two variables

$$
p(a, b, c) = p(a)p(b | a)p(c | b)
$$

### Question

Could anyone kindly explain why the equation shows that the probability distribution over three variables is represented as a product over two variables?

I can see that the right side of the equation that both a and b are used in conditional probabilities, and I suspect this is to do with the chain rule of conditional probabilities, but I can't concretely work it out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Factoring of conditional probability](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20034/factoring-of-conditional-probability)