# Putting into words conditional probabilities and the chain rule

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, independence

Consider events $a, b, c, d$.

$p(a,b,c,d) = p(a)p(b|a)p(c|a,b)p(d|a,b,c)$ ; by the chain rule.

We derive this by repeatedly applying the *definition* of conditional probability. This feels a bit dry, so I'm wondering how to put this into words in such a way that it *feels* true. Equivalently, develop an intuition why this is true.

My first attempt is *fixed worlds*:

> *Fix* part of the world with some probability, and from there onwards calculate the probability of other events in this *fixed* world,
>   recursively. We combine these *fixes* through multiplication.

In the example, fix $a$ getting the $a$ world, then fix $b$ in the $a$ world, getting the $a,b$ world, then fix $c$ in the $a,b$ world, getting the $a,b,c$ world, and finally fix $d$ in the $a,b,c$ world.

The multiplication part is what causes discomfort. It seems to imply independence between the fixing of the world and the probability of other events within this fixed world. How do we justify this?

Another example:

$p(a,b|c) = p(b|c)p(a|b,c)$

Again we can use the chain rule to derive this result, but how do we justify it with words, with intuition?

Perhaps we can we use *fixed worlds* again: in the $c$ world, fix $b$ with some probability, getting a new $b,c$ world. Now try to fix $a$.

I'm looking for critiques of this fixed world idea, comments on the multiplication discomfort, and other ways of intuiting the chain rule and conditional probability.

Thanks and sorry if this sounds confusing!

**Update**

So the discomfort in the multiplication comes from the independence rule that "if two events are independent, multiply their individual probabilities to get the joint probability". Thinking more deeply, this is a *specific case* of the multiplication rule, which in fact comes from a more general concept: when you are doing ANDs between events, the natural thing to do is multiply (when ORing, the natural thing is addition). The *general case* is multiplying while accounting for the state of the world (equivalently: upon which events we have conditioned so far).

This tree illustrates the idea more clearly for a 3 event ($a, b, c$) joint probability. Nodes correspond to fixed worlds, edges to transition probabilities between fixed worlds. The probability of reaching a final state is simply the product of the transition probabilities from the universe to the desired fixed world.

[image: p tree]

We can sprinkle some independence into the tree. For this example, let us suppose that $a$ and $b$ are independent events. The only thing that changes are the corresponding edge probabilities, but the *general* idea of *multiplication* to get to fixed worlds still holds.

[image]

Comment: See [this answer of mine](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/20060/6633) for a wordy (and possibly even intuitive) explanation of why $P(A\cap B) = P(A)P(B\mid A)$ and why there is no _independence of worlds_ issue in multiplying the probabilities: the $a,b$ world as you call it is a subworld of the $a$ world.

Comment: People tend to think more clearly about proportions than about probabilities. 
to this end, conditional probabilities can be conceived of as flows of a conserved quantity through a branching network (think of water in leak-free pipes). The amount found flowing out of $d$ after passing from $a$ to $b$ to $c$ to $d$ is the amount reaching $a$ times the proportion passing from $a$ to $b$ times the proportion passing from the path $ab$ to $c$ times the proportion passing from the path $abc$ to $d.$ Your diagrams clearly shows these paths. What are "worlds" needed for?